# Why DI for `FormBuilder` fails if used like this `private fb: FormBuilder`

Tags: angular, angular2-di

I'm trying to inject `FormBuilder` class like this into component:

```
@Component({
   ...
})
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
```

However, it fails and I get the error:

> (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for TaskComponent:
>   (?).↵ Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TaskComponent: (?).

If I change the constructor to this form:

```
constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) fb: FormBuilder) {    }
```

It's working fine. What's the problem?

Comment: FormBuilder is not marked as @Injectable

Comment: @Zyga, it's not required according to [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html) if FormBuilder is not injecting anything

Comment: Sorry, it seems that you are right. In similar article tho they inject FormBuilder with no issues (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html) so maybe its a setup issue then? Or the version of Angular you use?

Comment: yeah, I'll probably check with other injectables

Comment: Fair play, thats good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't have

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true
```

in `tsconfig.json` and so this part wasn't generated by `tsc`:

```
TaskComponent = __decorate([
    core_1.Component({
        moduleId: module.id,
        selector: 'task',
        templateUrl: 'task.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['task.component.css']
    }),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [forms_1.FormBuilder])
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
], TaskComponent);
```